# Rails: undefined local variable or method `resource' Toastr Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, toastr

I wanted to add toastr-rails to my application and now I'm getting the following error.

undefined local variable or method `resource' for #<#:0x854eb18>

In the first application everything worked fine, I don't know what went wrong this time...

Probably there is a conflict between gems ?

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.3.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'duktape'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~>3.3.6'
gem 'devise', '~>4.2'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'toastr-rails', '~>1.0'
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'active_skin'
```

User.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable,
         :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:google_oauth2]

  validates :fullname, presence: true, length: {maximum: 25}

  def self.from_omniauth(access_token)
    data = access_token.info
    user = User.where(email: data['email']).first

    unless user
    user = User.create(name: data['name'],
                     email: data['email'],
    password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
         )
     end
    user
end
end
```

Application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:fullname])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:fullname])
  end
end
```

_devisemes.html.erb

```
<% unless resource.errors.empty? %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |value| %>
      toastr.error('<%= value %>')
    <% end %>
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Add your toastr gem to your gemfile.**

```
gem 'toastr-rails', '~> 1.0'
```

**2. In your application.js you will need to add `//= require toastr`**

**3. In your stylesheet.scss you will need to import toastr `@import "toastr";`**

**4. Then run `bundle install` in your terminal**

**5. Then go to view/shared folder and create a partial view file and name it `_message.html.erb`. Inside add the following:**

```
<% unless flash.empty? %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <% type = key.to_s.gsub('alert','error').gsub('notice','success') %>
      toastr['<%= type %>']('<%= value %>')
    <% end %>
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Basically you're saying If flash is not empty run what's inside the script. In the script you creating a new variable called `type` then look for every single flash, but toastr does not have `notice` or `alert` but toastr does support the type `error` and `success`. So we can get a key from flash, then change it to a string and replace alert with error `('alert','error')` and replace `('notice','success')` then we say `toastr['<%= type %>']('<%= value %>')` which is some thing like `toastr['error']('Full name can not be blank')`

**6. Now you need to render this partial view inside all your devise views.**

**7 Go to application.html.erb and render the shared message in the partial view. Something like this: `<%= render shared/message %>`. You most likely want to render this under your navbar partial view if you have one in application.html.erb**

**8. Now go back to your app, log out and log back in and you should get the notification message.**

For the messages in all your devise views inside the views/devise folder you will 
find something like this `<%= devise_error_messages! %>` You'd pretty much do the same thing. Just a little differently.